# Recursive system of equations

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose you play a game with another person where you are given $f(0)=1000$ before the start of the game, and the person who offered the game puts down $n$ pennies and $n$ dimes. The number of rounds is $2n$ before it ends. Say $i$ is the round of a game, and each round they permanently discard a coin, but before they do this you are able to predict the coin that will be removed. This amount is $b(i)=p(i)f(i-1)$ for some $p(i)\in[0, 1]$. Here's the thing: the other person sees the bet you make and then removes the coin. So the amount you win based on whether or not you guess correctly and what your prediction was is the following system $$f(i):=\begin{cases} f(i-1)+b(i), \hspace{0.5cm} \text{if prediction is correct} \\ 
f(i-1)-b(i), \hspace{0.5cm}\text{else} \end{cases}$$

My question is: how do I find how large $f(2n)$ becomes?

---

My progress:
The first thing I notice is that there are $2n$ coins, half pennies and half dimes. The second thing I notice is that I can reduce $f(i)$ into $f(i-1)\biggr[1\pm p(i)\biggr], p(i)=0.01 \text{ or } 0.10$. I took a table of values for every best/worst scenario to get a sense of what's happening,
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline \text{Bet pennies correctly} & \text{Bet dimes correctly} \\ \hline 1000(1.01)=1010 & 1000(1.1)=1100 \\ \hline 1010(1.01)=1020.1 & 1100(.1)=1210 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1.01\cdot f(n) & 1.1\cdot f(n) \\ \hline \text{Bet pennies incorrectly} & \text{Bet dimes incorrectly} \\ \hline 1000(0.99)=990 & 1000(0.9)=900 \\ \hline 990(0.99)=980.1 & 900(0.9)=810 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 0.99\cdot f(n) & 0.9\cdot f(n) \\ \hline\end{array}
And so I'm thinking we let $M=B(p,d)$ represent the maximum bonus factor given $p$ pennies, $d$ dimes. If this maximum exists, then with you starting with $x$ dollars then  the maximum bonus must be $xB(p,d); p, d > 0$. Since there are $n$ pennies and $n$ dimes and we have $2n$ rounds of this game, then that means $p+d\le 2n$. If a penny is discarded, then we have $xB(p-1, d)$ dollars and likewise if a dime is discarded then we have $xB(p, d-1)$ dollars. But at this point I don't know how to continue. Currently I suspect there's no gain for the player since the opponent sees every bet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote by $g(p,d)$ the amount of money you need, when there are $p$ pennies and $d$ dimes, to get $1$ at the end of the game. Then the resulting value you seek is $f(2n)=1000/g(n,n)$.

Clearly, $g(0,0)=1$ and, moreover, $g(p,0)=2^{-p}$ and $g(0,d)=2^{-d}$, as you may bet all your money fearlessly at each round.

Now assume $p\geq d\geq 1$ (we will see that $g(p-1,d)\geq g(p,d-1)$ in this case). Then it is easy to see that you should have
$$
  \frac{g(p,d-1)+g(p-1,d)}2,
$$
of money, and bet
$$
  \frac{g(p-1,d)-g(p,d-1)}2
$$
on pennies (if you have less money, at least in one situation you get less than you need).

After that, you easily see by induction on $d+p$ that
$$
  g(d,p)=2^{-(d+p)}{d+p\choose p}.
$$

Hence the answer to your question is
$$
  f(2n)=1000\cdot 2^{2n}\cdot {2n\choose n}^{-1}\sim 1000\sqrt{\pi n}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, this answer hasn't worked out for me

Comment: So what's the trouble?

Comment: he didn't specify, he just put in question marks around the fractions you put in and like 5 more question marks next to the conclusion  lol

Comment: Hm.Whom are you talking about?

Comment: wait actually your solution was correct, it just needs further explanation

Comment: I understand how you got $g(p-1,d)\ge \frac{g(p,d-1)+g(p-1,d)}2$, but can you explain why this means that i should bet $\frac{g(p-1,d)-g(p,d-1)}2$ on pennies?